# Scrape Website By Selecting Dropdown Attributes without name using Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape website table for each date from dropdown https://wm.watchsystems.com/stpsocivil/realestatesl.html

I had to use Excel/VBA but struggling to find dropdown object to select each date using loop

I tried getElementsByName to select whole salelist also tried to get element by id, coudlnt select anything correctly to have selected dates from dropdowns

```
Set Post = objIE.document.getElementByAttributeName("cboSaleDate")

For Each elem In Post.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If Len(elem.Value) > 4 Then
       elem.Selected = True
       Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End If
Next elem

Set hBody = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
```

I want to select each date using loop and then get displayed table to scrape data from (I am using loop for each tr and td for getting data from table, just cant get to table itself yet)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped looping through link: https://wm.watchsystems.com/stpsocivil/realSalesList.asp
and instead of names I did loop through

```
k = 0
For Each date_picked In .document.getElementsByTagName("select").Item(0)
k = k + 1
.document.getElementsByTagName("select").Item(0).selectedIndex = k
.document.getElementsByTagName("select").Item(0).FireEvent ("onchange")
next
```